# Linq to SQL valid Email Address in a where clause

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to return the contact records from my Contacts table but only where the contact email address is valid. So something like the following:

```
var contacts = (from cont in db.Contacts
                        where cont.Accounts_CustomerID == accountId
                        && ValidEmail(cont.EmailAddress)
                        select new ContactLight
                        {
                            AccountId = cont.Accounts_CustomerID,
                            FirstName = cont.Firstname,
                            LastName = cont.Lastname,
                            EmailAddress = cont.EmailAddress
                        });

private static bool ValidEmail(string email)
{
    if(email == "")
        return false;
    else
        return new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,6}$").IsMatch(email);
}
```

I am getting "Method 'Boolean ValidEmail(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL." so I assume a method with Regex cannot be translated. What's the best way around this?

Comment: pull the data out and then run the validEmail where clause on the objects

Comment: Anything you use in SQL which is part of the Where clause like that will be compiled to SQL in some form. A custom Regex matching function you've written can't be translated to SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your email validation to client (Linq-to-Objects).

```
var contacts = db.Contacts
    .Where(cont.Accounts_CustomerID == accountId)
    .Select(cont => new ContactLight
                    {
                        AccountId = cont.Accounts_CustomerID,
                        FirstName = cont.Firstname,
                        LastName = cont.Lastname,
                        EmailAddress = cont.EmailAddress
                    })
    .AsEnumerable() //this forces request to client side
    .Where(e => ValidEmail(e.EmailAddress));
```

Comment: This answer is excellent as you project just the columns you need (not the entire entity).

Comment: Thanks Serg, I like the idea. I will give it a test and look at performance (I have 134,000 records).